# Online mod_rewrite testing tool

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, debugging

mod_rewrite statements can be hard to write and debug, therefore I need a lightweight online tool that enables me to test my `RewriteCond`, `RewriteRule` statements on the fly.

Any such tool?

Answer (score 7):

Here's [one](http://civilolydnad.se/projects/rewriterule/). You can also use a regex tester like [this one](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/), or [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).

Comment: The first link does not support RewriteCond right now :-(

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is to just set up development Apache and use [**`RewriteLog`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLog), and set [**`RewriteLogLevel`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLogLevel) high (above 3).

Comment: This can be only be set in the context of server config and virtual host.

Comment: As stated in the description, what's the problem with that ? Sure it's not an "online" tool but it's way better than any of them and reloading apache is quick.